# "I usually knock off at 6"

Tags: american-english, british-english, australian-english

"I usually knock off at 6", i heard an english gentleman say that. Does it sound odd only to me? In fact, what I heard was "I usually masturbate at 6"

Did some research:

found a book (i'm guessing it's for non native speakers) advanced vocab in use; it says:

[image]

It would definitely sound like something sexually oriented in the US. So, the book says it's informal for "finishing work"; [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knock+off) says the same (7th meaning is " to have sexual intercourse with; to seduce")

So i have severalquestions:

> 1 Does this phrase have any sexual connotations in the UK or Australia?
>
> 2 How much is it used in the UK and Australia (meaning "finishing work")?
>
> 3 Does this vocab sentence sound odd to you (British and Australians (and Americans))

Comment: In the US, "knock off work at X PM" is a very common way to express when one leaves a job for the day.  Absolutely nothing sexual implied.

Comment: I would differ with you here that it's a very common way as the majority of people I know would never say that maybe it's just that I never heard about that expression maybe that's the problem but it sounds odd to many people I asked around here depends on a person I'd say

Comment: You can differ all you want, but you'll be wrong. In every context I have ever been aware "knock off" refers to finishing work.

Comment: I just want to validate your concern, Alex.  The people you are polling here are not in their teens or early twenties.  To my (US) ear, there's nothing sexual implied.  But you might get a different answer from a younger crowd.

Comment: @aparente001 well, yeah i guess that's correct i was just thinking about that too, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Britain 'to knock off [work]' is a perfectly normal and innocent thing to say. It is informal so you might more often hear 'to finish work' or 'to leave work'.

I've never heard it used to mean 'masturbate'.

In Britain someone might say 'to knock one out' to mean masturbate but the addition of the words 'one' and 'out' makes the verb completely different.

Comment: Whilst I agree entirely with your first paragraph (about work), I would add that it also has a sexual connotation - which may be slightly dated - though I have never known the two to be confused, other than by someone intent on creating a *double entendre*. I agree that I have never known it to mean 'to masturbate'. And I do not recognise the sense in your final paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, the man was on the phone and when he said it I was like "what!?" It was bizarre really was

Comment: @WS2 - I've just corrected my final paragraph.

Comment: I've never known it use for 'masturbate' in Br Eng, but the OED usage of 'copulate' is well known (though perhaps a bit out of date), and also "knocking shop" for "brothel". But there is no innuendo in saying "knock off" for "finish work". That is the same usage as the imperative "knock it off!" meaning "stop it!".

Comment: maybe it's one of those pleasurable ways to "finish" something?

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing "knock off" used for "masturbate" -- the term I heard most commonly (which was not all that often) was "jack off".  "Knock off", of course, has other meanings, such as to kill someone with premeditation.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock%20off), an American dictionary, also has a definition that would allow *"knock off work"*.

> *intransitive verb*:  to stop doing something
>
> *transitive verb* 2 :  discontinue, stop <knocked off work at five>

I am American, know this definition, and would definitely assume that someone meant *"stop working"* if he said *"I usually knock off at 6".*

Comment: What state are you from?

Comment: I've lived in Washington D.C., California, Massachusetts, and New Jersey. I have no idea where I learned the expression *"knocked off"* for *"stopped"*.

Comment: I lived in MA all my life knock it off is fine by me but I knock off at 6 - stop working - come on

Comment: Alex, I'm from NY and to me, "finish work" is the only meaning I would understand.  However, most people, in this context, would say "knock off work."

Comment: Its use seems to be declining in both AmE and BrE, [Google N-grams](https://goo.gl/nWd4wW) so maybe there's an age effect.

Answer (score 1):

Australian English follows British usage; i.e. it is common to say 'knock off from work'. There are other (Australian) meanings: to steal something ("I knocked it off"), a counterfeit product ("its just a cheap knock-off"), and to desist ("hey, knock it off, you two"). "They knocked him off" means they killed someone. I (native born Australian, and getting old now), have never heard it used to mean anything sexual. On the other hand, to be 'knocked up' ("Jack knocked her up") is to be made pregnant illegitimately, and to 'knock up' something is to make something roughly ('I knocked up a pergola on the weekend')

Comment: In AE (east coast, at least) the "make something roughly" notion is "knocked **out**."

Comment: @PapaPoule, my understanding of AE 'k. out' is e.g., "the factory just keeps knocking them out as fast as they can", as in, making a number of something.

Comment: Re:*knock off*. All of the uses you mention (except the one meaning 'desist') are familiar to us in the UK. I am surprised to hear that it is not used Down Under for anything sexual. How about *knocking shop*?  There are also various cricket uses, which I'm sure you know all about. As regards *knocked up*, I wasn't aware of the 'pregnancy' implication but 'to make something roughly' is certainly a UK use.  Wouldn't you also use *knocked up* to mean 'exhausted' e.g. from playing rugby?

Comment: @WS2 _Knocked up_ is definitely used for pregnancy in the UK as well, though I suspect (without bothering to check) that both it and “knock it off!” are AmE in origin. (Slight niggle: surely the desisting sense is _familiar_ to those in the UK, just not really actively used?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Re *knocked up* meaning 'made pregnant'. The OED includes this meaning (noting *orig US*). Speaking personally, I had never heard it used in that way until now.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Yes - the 'desist' sense is known in the UK. Maybe it's gone out of fashion but I still use it.

Answer (score 0):

The expression ***to knock off*** has many senses, all of them colloquial. Below is the OED entry. Sense 12 is the only one relating to sex. Its first example is from 1942, which suggests (from what the OP says about its use in America) it may have been introduced to Britain by American servicemen arriving about that time. No mention is made anywhere of its referring to masturbation.

**to knock off** - OED entry. (Only the most recent example of each sense is given, though some date from as early as 1616. Sense 1 is found in Shakespeare.)

1. trans. To strike off by or as by a blow; also fig. to knock off a person's head                                        , to ‘beat’ or surpass him.

1862   Cornhill Mag. June 655,   I could knock his head off in Greek Iambics.

2. To cause to desist or leave off from work; to discharge or dismiss from employment, to ‘lay off’.

1955   Times 9 June 8/3   The Cunard company put the main restaurant at his service and the staff captain ‘knocked off all the men from their duties’.

3. intr. To desist, leave off; to cease from one's work or occupation; slang to die.

1916   ‘Boyd Cable’ Doing their Bit iii. 49   The factory was knocking off for dinner as we came away.

1969   M. Crouch Essex ii. 28   One who has just knocked off for his tea-break.

4. trans. To stop, discontinue, give up (work).

1885   R. Buchanan Matt viii,   He at once knocked off painting for the day.

5. To dispatch, dispose of, put out of hand, accomplish; to complete or do hastily; spec. to write, paint, etc., in a hurried and perfunctory fashion. colloq.

1970   W. Garner Puppet-masters xv. 124   Look, you could knock off a few hundred words on Baxx without so much as scratching the surface of your magnum opus.

6. To strike off, deduct from an amount or sum.

1972   Daily Tel. 30 Mar. 19/2   The gloomy assessment..knocked 12p off ICI's share price in London.

7. Cricket. Of batsmen, to score the runs requisite for victory, or to oblige (a bowler) to be taken off by scoring heavily from his bowling.

1963   A. Ross Australia 63 18   Pullar and Cowdrey knocked off the 49 required to win without actually being separated.

8. [imp. use of  3.] knock it off! : leave off! stop it!

1961   J. Heller Catch-22 (1962) xxvii. 294   ‘Hey, knock it off down there,’ a voice rang out from the far end of the ward. ‘Can't you see we're trying to nap?’

9. slang. To steal, to rob. Also transf.

1973   A. Hunter Gently French iii. 24   Just met a bloke..in the nick... Him what was in there for knocking-off cars.

10. slang (orig. U.S.). To kill; to murder.

1973   C. Mullard Black Brit. i. ii. 24   In one village a white launched a murder campaign because ‘he liked knocking off blacks’.

11. Underworld slang. To arrest (a person); to raid (an establishment).
    1969   R. V. Beste Next Time I'll Pay xi. 157   You're the sort who'd knock off his mother because she hadn't got a lamp on her bike five minutes after lighting up time.
12. slang. To copulate with, to seduce (a woman).

1974   Times Lit. Suppl. 11 Oct. 1109/4   Knocking off his best friend's busty wife during boozy sprees on leave in Soho.

> Blockquote

Comment: Thanks, do you know anything about Australia how it's used there?